# Use of wrong HTTP verb while creating elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, post, put, http-protocols

To create an index in the elasticsearch, we need to use the `PUT` verb, for example, the following command:

`curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test_index" -d '{"settings":{"number_of_shards":2, "number_of_replicas":2}}' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'`

But according to [RFC 2616, § 9.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5), `POST` can be also used to create a resource.

Why `POST` is not suitable here or why did elasticsearch designer use `PUT` instead of `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

I found some posts related to your question.
This answer from one of the ElasticSearch engineers might be helpful to you.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/when-to-use-put-versus-post/68550/3